# Python quick question about comprehensions vs list comprehensions

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Just wanted to ask why this(list comprehension, if I'm not mistaken):

```
def s(number):
    return sum([n for n in range(number) if n%3==0 or n%5==0])
s(100)
```

is twice as fast(108 steps on visualize python) as this(202 steps):

```
def s(number):
    return sum(n for n in range(number) if n%3==0 or n%5==0)
s(100)
```

?

And also, although the first code is faster, does the second code have any advantages in any cases? Maybe, uses less memory? Just spitballing, don''t really have any idea what I'm talking about. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first one is creating a complete list in memory, and then goes over that list again to `sum` it. The second one `sum`s the items directly as they are generated by the generator expression. The first one is less efficient, but the second one may be visualised as taking more steps due to the way the execution is being visualised… BTW, link to that visualiser please…

Comment: @John Doe Did you benchmarked both the functions?. I don't see much difference while I `timeit`. May be the **steps** shown in the visualizer is completely depends on how the code is being visualized?(ie, not the performace)

Comment: "List comprehension is faster because it is optimized for the Python interpreter to spot a predictable pattern during looping."
See this artice: [click here](https://nyu-cds.github.io/python-performance-tips/08-loops/)

Comment: @deceze Here's the link: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display

Comment: @abdulNiyasPM I didn't actually 'timeit', just visualized it on the link provided above. It appears I should have. So both methods are quite identical in terms of performance/memory usage?

Comment: @EldarOmerovic Will check your link out now, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance of both of your snippets is quite similar, apparently not every step is equal. For small values of `number` first code (list) is slightly faster, but for larger `number` second code (generator) wins.

Other thing is memory usage - creating a list requires amount of memory proportional to its size, so larger `number` consumes more RAM. Moreover, as list grows it requires memory reallocations, which eventually triggers garbage collector (`timeit()` by default disables `gc`, mangling results). 
On the other hand, generator version uses the same (minimal) amount of memory for any `number`.

The conclusion is that you should use generator expressions whenever possible. It's especially important when you care of memory footprint and/or you operate on large numbers. Also, this way your code is slightly shorter and cleaner (arguable).

This subject is explained in [PEP 289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), introducing generator expressions.

Comment: Thank you for such an all-encompassing answer!